# CSS positioning query

Tags: css, positioning

I have a webpage with a background graphic that is 1024x768. My CSS and HTML is below. I also have a header graphic and a left side menu that is formatted text.

I want to create a template page. Everything is OK except...

I have a footer that I want to display at the bottom of the background area. How do I position that so that no matter what content I add the footer stays put? Not fixed as in position: fixed but placed in a preset position.

I have tried using a `div` tag to surround all but the footer with a width and height specified. I then added a `div` for the footer and expected it to position itself outside the first `div`. Clearly I have misunderstood.

[JSFiddle with following HTML and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/EvTCS/)

**HTML**

```
<body>

<div id="allcontent">

<div id="header">
<img src="images/xxxxxxxxxxx.png" alt="xxxxxxxxx" />
<br /</div>
<div id="menu">
<a href="home" alt="Go to home page">Home</a> 
<br />
<br />
<a href="weddings" alt="Go to home page">Weddings</a>
<br />
<br />
<a href="portraits" alt="Go to home page">Portraits</a>
<br />
<br />
<a href="blog" alt="Go to home page">Blog</a>
<br />
<br />

<a href="contact" alt="Contact Us">Connect</a>
</div>

</div>
<div id="footer">
<div id="phone">
tel. xxxxxxxx
</div>
<div id="email">
email: xxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk
</div>
<br />
<div id="copy">
&copy; 2012, xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
<br />
  Website constructed by <a class="footlink" href="http://xxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk" target="_blank">xxxxxxx</a>      
 </div>

</div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
font-family:    Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:      large;
width:  auto;
margin-left:    auto;
margin-right:   auto;
background-color:   #451918;
color:  #221b1b;

}
div#allcontent  {
width: 1024px;
height: 768px;
margin-left:    auto;
margin-right:   auto;
background-image:   url("images/web page background 1024x768.jpg");
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
}
a   {   
text-decoration:    none;
}

div#menu    {
float:  left;
}
div#header  {
padding-top: 50px;
padding-left: 50px;
text-align: left;
}
div#footer  {
bottom: 0;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
font-size:  85%;
color:  #221b1b;
}
div#copy    {
font-size:  50%;
}
div#phone   {
font-size:  85%;
margin-left:    40px;
float:  left;
}
div#email   {
margin-right:   40px;
font-size:  85%;
float:  right;
}
a.footlink:link {
color:  #221b1b;
}
a.footlink:visited  {
color:  #221b1b;
}
a.footlink:hover    {
color:  #226225
}
a:link {
color: #9c7f7f;
}
a:hover {
color: #221b1b;
}
a:visited {
color: #5f4d4d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There **float** in your `menu` so you have to clear it. Give `clear:both` on `#footer`. Like this:

```
#footer  {
 clear:both
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. Adding clear:both helps in that it shifts the footer below the menu but it doesn't shift it to the bottom of the page background which is what I was after. Any further ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to clear the floats of any `div` that precedes the footer.

Go ahead and set `clear:both` to #footer to see if it addresses the issue.

If all is well, you won't need to set heights for any of the elements before the footer, nor apply any of the workarounds that you may have tried.

Refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EvTCS/2/)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. Adding clear:both helps in that it shfits the footer below the menu but it doesn't shift it to the bottom of the page background which is what I was after. Any further ideas??

Comment: In that case, set a height for #allcontent to accommodate the size of the image. Then, add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` to the end of #allcontent (right before the closing tag, </div>) and all should work well. Here's a fiddle to show you what your markup should resemble. I took the liberty to use a comment to show you where the clear div should be placed. http://jsfiddle.net/EvTCS/5/

Comment: @user1281545 Comment for you.

Answer (score 0):

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

here is the trick. You can follow the link to a tutorial for positioning footer